# Add PhoneAccentBrush into image

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

is there any way I can add PhoneAccentBrush into image? So I get some arrow style image that I want it change according to phone theme like Red or blue or so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another thought.
Instead of modifying the image itself, put a polygon that draws a arrow with PhoneAccentBrush on the image.
But it only works for the shape which is not too complicated.

```
<Grid Height="211" Width="211">
    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}"></Image>
    <Polygon Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Points="0,0 84,0 63,21 84,42 0,42" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrow should be transparent and you can use this code:

```
Grid g = new Grid();
g.Background = new SolidColorBrush( ( App.Current.Resources[ "PhoneAccentBrush" ] as SolidColorBrush ).Color );
g.Width = GetImageWidth( ... ); // Image Width
g.Height = GetImageHeight( ... ); // Image Height
Image someImage = new Image();
someImage.Source = new BitmapImage( new Uri( "/ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative ) ); // Your image
g.Children.Add( someImage );

int w = Convert.ToInt32( g.ActualWidth );
int h = Convert.ToInt32( g.ActualHeight );
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap( w, h );
wb.Render( g, null );
wb.Invalidate();
```